# Can't inherit, in Raku, a method trait from a class defined in the same file

Tags: raku

A method trait, defined with trait_mod, is flawlessly inherited from a class defined in an other file.
This doesn't seem to be working when the two classes are defined in the same file.

The 2 following files are working fine together:

```
# mmm.pm6

class TTT is export  {

    multi trait_mod:<is> (Routine $meth, :$something! ) is export
    {
        say "METH : ", $meth.name;
    }
}
```

```
# aaa.p6

use lib <.>;
use mmm;

class BBB is TTT {
    method work is something {  }
}
```

Output is: `METH : work`

But the same code gathered in the following unique file gives an error message

```
# bbb.p6

class TTT is export  {

    multi trait_mod:<is> (Routine $meth, :$something! ) is export
    {
        say "METH : ", $meth.name;
    }
}

class BBB is TTT {
    method work is something {  }
}
```

Output is:

```
===SORRY!=== Error while compiling /home/home.mg6/yves/ygsrc/trait/bbb.p6
Can't use unknown trait 'is' -> 'something' in a method declaration.
at /home/home.mg6/yves/ygsrc/trait/bbb.p6:12
    expecting any of:
        rw raw hidden-from-backtrace hidden-from-USAGE pure default
        DEPRECATED inlinable nodal prec equiv tighter looser assoc
        leading_docs trailing_docs
```

I'm running this Rakudo version:

```
This is Rakudo Star version 2019.03.1 built on MoarVM version 2019.03
implementing Perl 6.d.
```

Why can't I run this code from a single file ?
What did I miss ?

Comment: There is some more information about how the export trait is working [here](https://docs.raku.org/language/modules#UNIT::EXPORT::*)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.raku.org/language/module-packages#When_to_use_modules):

> Module contents (classes, subroutines, variables, etc.) can be
>   exported from a module with the `is export` trait; these are available
>   in the caller's namespace once the module has been imported with
>   `import` or `use`.

You can try using `import` to import the `is` trait into the current package:

**bbb.p6**:

```
module X {  # <- declare a module name, e.g. 'X' so we can import it later..
    class TTT is export  {
        multi trait_mod:<is> (Routine $meth, :$something! ) is export
        {
            say "METH : ", $meth.name;
        }
    }
}

import X;
class BBB is TTT {
    method work is something {  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixes my issue.

Comment: I discovered that "import TTT;" can also be used without using the module declaration.